# Create a 3D (partially) diagonal array from a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'd like to ask how can I efficiently generate a numpy 3D array from a 2D array with each row filling the diagonal part of the new array?
For example, the input 2D array is

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

and I want the output to be

```
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[3, 0],
        [0, 4]],

       [[5, 0],
        [0, 6]],

       [[7, 0],
        [0, 8]]])
```

Typically, the size of the first dimensional is very large. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you currently generating, and why don't you consider it efficient enough?

Comment: I used a for-loop to diag each row, but this is low efficient since normally the input array contains thousands of rows

Comment: `np.einsum('jk,kl->jkl', arr, np.eye(2, dtype=int))` or `arr[...,None] * np.eye(2, dtype=int)[None]`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thanks so much for your reply. It works nicely with the einsum :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a` the input and using indexing with [`unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html#numpy.unravel_index):

```
x, y = np.unravel_index(np.arange(a.size), a.shape)

out = np.zeros(a.shape+(a.shape[-1],), dtype=a.dtype)

out[x, y, y] = a.flat
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[3, 0],
        [0, 4]],

       [[5, 0],
        [0, 6]],

       [[7, 0],
        [0, 8]]])
```

##### timings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
res = np.apply_along_axis(np.diag, 1, arr)
```